# Magento - show price range of simple products

Tags: magento

Is it possible in Magento to show the price range of simple products as opposed to the price set for the main configurable product.

For example, say we have a t shirt, configurable by size and each with a different price.  It doesnt make sense to show a fixed price on the catalog page does it?

I would expect to see something similar to Prices from £3.99.

Does anyone know if this is possible without any custom modification.

Comment: did you find the solution? I am looking for same thing too.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is NOT good solution but worth to try.

Create simple products of each t-shirt based size then group this products like "Polo T-Shirt". Users will see only "Polo T-Shirt" but they can choose what they want from drop-down list.